# Connecting two instances within the same network in google-cloud-platform

Tags: linux, networking, google-cloud-platform

I want to connect two instances that do not have external IP addresses. Both instances are in the same region.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "connect two instances". What exactly are you trying to do? SSH from one instance to another and got an error? sFTP connection? Calling a web service? Post your code or command, and the error message, as well as what you want to do

Comment: there was a problem on google platform for two days now it works just fine